# Adding Dependency jars to a personal Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, dependencies

**Short Version**

In Eclipse, when you export a program as a jar, is there a way to add all of the Referenced Libraries right into the jar so that it doesn't go looking for its dependencies elsewhere?

**Long Version**

I am using IBM Business Process Manager 8.5 built on WebSphere. I am allowed to upload a jar and use public functions inside it. I created a PDF Utility that uses Apache XSL-FO and requires a fop.jar, xmlgraphics-commons-1.5.jar, commons-logging-1.0.4.jar, commons-io-1.3.1.jar, avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar, and batik-all-1.7.jar. BPM already has and is using the two commons and the avalon jar. The problem I'm running into is I get a hung thread when I run my PDF java code because it tries to pull the three dependencies from BPM. I need to find a way to prevent it from searching for those dependencies. FYI, I know that I'm not missing any jars because I found a non-supported workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you export a project as a **runnable** jar in Eclipse, there's a radio button to either extract or package required libraries into the generated jar. Try one of those and see what happens.